# PHP MVC - session not persisting

Tags: php, templates, session

I'm building my own MVC framework in order to learn the ropes properly.

Ive managed to get a login system working, but sessions dont seem to be persisting across page changes.

Ive done some reason reading around and am running `session_start()` in the controller as a few people seem to be directing.

On login, my processLogin method runs successfully and stores the session data as expected.  I know this has happened because Im doing a `var_dump` on it in the main header file and its there when the login form loads (im not destroying it at any point).

The trouble I have is when it comes to do a location change after successful login, it runs the 'gallery' method, the session array is still there, but empty.

Its exasperating and Id really appreciate any help.

Heres my extended controller class for reference:

```
session_start();

class Home extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        require 'application/views/_templates/header.php';
        require 'application/views/home/index.php';
        require 'application/views/_templates/footer.php';
    }

    // login function (validation carried out client side)
    public function processLogin() {
        if (isset($_POST['loginUsername'])) {
            $home_model = $this->loadModel("HomeModel");
            $home_model->processLogin($_POST['loginUsername'],   $_POST['loginPassword']);
        }
    }

    public function gallery() {
        require 'application/views/_templates/header.php';
        require 'application/views/home/gallery.php';
        require 'application/views/_templates/footer.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `$_SESSION` code in this code so how can we help you?

Comment: sorry missed the session_start line (doh!). corrected.

Comment: Two notes: 1. this isn't really and MVC pattern, especially since you do not have the any views (what you have are glorified [templates](http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html)); 2. you should treat the session the same way as you treat database - as a form as storage. This also means that you should be iterating with it through some shared abstraction (that same way as you would be when using PDO or MySQLi).

Comment: hmms interesting. I do have views, theyre loaded from the controller.  the header and footer are indeed templates, but the rest is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should use `session_start()` at the beginning of main file, usually `index.php` and not in Controller (because we don't know how your framework is build.

You should make sure that everywhere in your webpage you use the same domain - for example with www. or without www. Otherwise you should use [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to set it other way (for example for all subdomains)

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Ive tried putting `session_start()` in the header.php file which is called everywhere, but that isnt fixing the issue.  Also using the same domain everywhere.

Comment: ok fixed it. What an idiot I am..

in my model file I was redirecting like this.. header('location: ' . URL . 'home/gallery');

not like this.. header('location: ../home/gallery');

obviously changing the domain. Thank you Marcin, it was your answer that gave me the clue.